# Bitbucket - Webhook keep returning error 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bitbucket, webhooks

Would like to check, I am fairly new to Bitbucket's new introduced webhook where previously i was using services where Bitbucket will execute a link to my site thus triggering a deployment script.

So since the old service is going to be depreciated soon, we all migrated to webhook instead. With the same implementation, I keep getting an error 500 upon commit/push/merge and there is no way for us to see the details for the error given. At first I thought it was my server giving problem but when i call the link manually via browsers and everything was fine. The deployment script can be executed successfully so then why bitbucket's webhook keeps telling me error 500?

Subsequently I find the guide given by Bitbucket was not helpful. There is no specified call method to the url stated so is the webhook initiates a `GET` or `POST` request? previously using services initiates a `POST` request. Then, are there any necessary payloads i need to include into the webhook URL? None is stated. Then, if there is an error at least let me see the error so I can fix it instead of telling me error 500.

I hope someone here can help me with this issue. Below are some specification of the site.

```
Server : Ubuntu LEMP 14.04 x64 Laravel framework 5.0
Webhook Url: bot.example.com/bitbucket/deploy/{Site API}
Method : GET
```

And when the abode link is call, it reaches a controller that does

```
public function attemptDeploy($site_api)
{

    $script = 'nohup setsid php ~/scripts/deploy.php ' . $site_api. ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &';

    exec($script);
    return response('Deploy running.', 200);
}
```

Note that when i call this link manually either form browser or console everything works perfectly except from bitbucket's webhook. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: What do your `storage/logs` files tell you? Also you will need to allow both GET and POST requests for the webhook route.

Comment: @Jeemusu my error log file does not have any errors because it can be executed if i call from terminal or browser... the only problem is with Bitbucket's new webhook returns 500...

Comment: Yes... so when Bitbucket returns a 500 error your logs should have a record of it.

Comment: @Jeemusu apparently no... it is not recorded in any of the logs... how so?

Comment: I'm assuming your server is not hosted locally? It doesn't have some kind of htaccess authentication or other authentication applied to it, or the route in question? Also, have you tried making a POST request to it yourself?

Comment: @Jeemusu The server is not hosted locally... and the route is an open route where there are no any authentication applied to it. I tried making POST request myself and everything works perfectly...

Comment: Check the network tab of your browsers developer tools. When you do a POST request, what status code does it give you? I've seen requests appear to work, but looking closely revealed they where really responding with a 500 status code.

Comment: @Jeemusu Ok to reduce the amount of things i need to try, I have open the route to accept all call methods (POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, UPDATE), tried with browser, terminal, cross script, and everything works fine. Like you suggested in network tab, i get a return of 200. But yet when i push a code to bitbucket, there has an error 500...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88977/discussion-between-jeemusu-and-kenny-yap).

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same situation. Bitbucket trims the body of the response and I couldn't see the error given by my server.

I've looked into the logs `storage/logs/laravel.log` and saw *`TokenMismatchException`*. Webhooks being API calls they don't store cookies or sessions so CSRF from Laravel breaks.

You need to add an exception from CSRF for the bitbucket deploy route. You can add this exception in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`. For example if your link is `www.your_site.com/bit_deploy` you will have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'bit_deploy'
    ];
}
```

Hope that this helps you ... as I've lost 3 hours on this.

PS: at the time of writing this answer, bitbucket webhooks performs **POST** calls (not GET)